# SQLAlchemy Can't Find Column when adding ForeignKey to another table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been fighting this error for a few days now in a variety of configurations.
I tried adding Relationship lines under each of the ForeignKeys with no luck.
I also swapped my queries from using the declarative_base style calls to SQL queries.
The error only appears once I add the second ForeignKey to Task. (I originally had several foreign keys in Task and Project but pared things down until it worked and tried slowly adding things back. Adding the second ForeignKey did it no matter which table it was added to.)

My current Flask method is:

```
@app.route('/project/<int:project_id>/')
    def showProject(project_id):
        project = session.query(Project).from_statement(text("SELECT * FROM project WHERE project.id = project_id ORDER BY project.projnum DESC"))
        tasks = session.query(Task).filter_by(project_id = project_id).all()
        return render_template('project.html', project = project, tasks = tasks)
```

And I get a "no such column" error:

`OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: task.project_id [SQL: u'SELECT task.id AS task_id, task.name AS task_name, task.description AS task_description, task.assigned_id AS task_assigned_id, task.project_id AS task_project_id, task.due AS task_due \nFROM task \nWHERE task.project_id = ?'] [parameters: (2,)]`

This is the setup file for my database:

```
import os
import sys
import time
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///gmnpm.db')

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    picture = Column(String(250))

class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'task'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(2000))
    assigned_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    project_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('project.id'))
    due = Column(Integer, default=int(time.time()))

class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'project'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(1000))
    projnum = Column(Integer)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

After reading a bunch of documentation and going crazy trying random things on the off chance they work, I'm grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you perhaps added the `project_id` column later to you Task model, but not migrated the DB schema? Another thing: in `due = Column(Integer, default=int(time.time()))` the call to `time()` is evaluated during  class construction, so all your tasks will have the same default due time.

Comment: That did it! When I had previously made changes I had deleted my .db file (some of the time, and hadn't noticed that those were the times when things worked), this last change I had assumed (incorrectly) that running my database_setup file would overwrite my .db file. If you submit this as an answer I can accept it.